# Can $\mathbf{Rng}$ be made into a pre-additive category?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, rngs, additive-categories

**Question**: Can $\mathbf{Rng}$ be made into a pre-additive category?

---

[Rngs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)) are just rings, *without* the requirement of an identity. Accordingly, we do not require rng homomorphisms to preserve the identity (should it exist). These objects (rngs) and morphisms (rng homomorphisms) form the category $\mathbf{Rng}$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_rings#:%7E:text=The%20zero%20ring%20serves%20as,still%20not%20a%20preadditive%20category.) says that:

> Despite the existence of zero morphisms, Rng is still not a pre-additive category.

For a category to be pre-additive, we require a zero object, and an abelian group structure on the hom-sets. The pointwise sum of two rng homomorphisms is generally not a rng homomorphism - so certainly, $\mathbf{Rng}$ is not a pre-additive category with the obvious choice of addition (of homomorphisms). However, how do we know that $\mathbf{Rng}$ cannot be made into a pre-additive category, possibly by choosing **some other** addition operation on the hom-sets? All we need is an abelian group structure, and there are no restrictions on the group operation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doesn't a pre-additive category have to have the composition respect the hom addition in a distributive way?  I would think that would be the obstruction.  So, there are some restrictions on the group operation.

Comment: That's right, there should be some restrictions on the choice of the group operation - but it's hard to point out exactly what they are. @Randall

Comment: Is there some reason making every hom-set the trivial group wouldn't work?  (This is pretty useless.  You'd never be able to prove a theorem with this.)

Comment: I think that works, but I was trying to ignore the trivial group operation. Perhaps I should state that in the post. @Randall

Comment: Wait, what is the trivial group operation supposed to be?

Comment: You can't just "make the hom-sets" the trivial group. You can't choose the hom-sets, and they have more than $1$ element in general.

Comment: @CaptainLama I think Randall wanted to say $f + g = 0$ for all $f,g \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Rng}}(A,B)$ for all objects $A,B$? The zero morphism is well-defined, as the following composition
$$A \to \mathbf{0} \to B$$
where $\mathbf{0}$ denotes the zero object in $\mathbf{Rng}$.

Comment: But that is very clearly not a group operation.

Comment: Yes, that's right - it means every element is the inverse of every other element, which is certainly, extremely absurd. @CaptainLama

Comment: Oh right, I was thinking wrongly.

Comment: The product of two rngs $A$ and $B$ is $A \times B$. Is this also the coproduct (with the injections $a \mapsto (a,0)$ and $b \mapsto (0,b)$)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a preadditive category, any finite product or coproduct is a biproduct (see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/additive+category#properties) for a proof).  This is not true in $\mathbf{Rng}$: the product of two rngs $A$ and $B$ is just the usual cartesian product $A\times B$, but this is typically not a coproduct under the inclusion maps $i:A\to A\times B$ and $j:B\to A\times B$ (which are the identity on one coordinate and zero on the other).  In particular, these inclusions satisfy $i(a)j(b)=0$ for all $a\in A,b\in B$, so if they satisfied the universal property of the coproduct, the same would have to be true of any rng $C$ with homomorphisms from $A$ and $B$.  This is clearly false in general--for instance, if $A=B=C$ is a rng with nonzero multiplication, you could take the identity homomorphisms $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to C$ and these do not satisfy $f(a)g(b)=0$ for all $a\in A,b\in B$.

Note that more generally, since finite products or coproducts are biproducts in a preadditive category, any preadditive category with finite products or coproducts is additive, and then the addition operation on morphisms is actually *uniquely* determined by just the category structure (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3141906/86856) for instance).  That is, a category with finite products or coproducts admits at most one structure of a preadditive category.  So it makes sense to say such a category "is" preadditive or not, rather than saying it admits the structure of a preadditive category.